# SAS - how to create a dataset that shows if all required variables are in a original dataset

Tags: variables, sas, output, sas-macro

I am kind of new to SAS and struggle to program this.

I have to check if all required variables are in a dataset. If variables are missing, then the missing variables simply should be listed in a new dataset.

Lets say my original dataset (hotel) has 20 variables with 100 observations.

If 2 variables are missing, then the new dataset (misvar) should contain one variable that lists the 2 missinng variables from hotel.

What is the best way to do that?

I tried different things but nothing seemed to work.

I wrote this macro, it checks if a certain variable is in the dataset. If yes, the position of the variable appears in the Log. If no, then 0 appears in the log.

```
%macro varcheck (newvar, dataid);

%let daid = %sysfunc(open(&dsname));
%let vari = %sysfunc(varnum(&daid,&newvar));
%let clo = %sysfunc(close(&daid));

&val

%mend varcheck;
```

However, i struggled to combine this code with the other requirements as described at the beginning.

Comment: How are you keeping track of the required variables. A robust 'required variables' table would include the name, type and length of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to get into trying to use macro code to do this.

Let's assume you have a dataset with the list of required variables.  So something like:

```
data required;
  length name $32 ;
  input name @@ ;
cards;
ID DATE STATUS
;
```

Now let's make a dataset that has some but not all of those variables.

```
data have;
  length ID 8 DATE 8 REASON $100 ;
run;
```

Now we can make a dataset with the list of required variables that are not in HAVE with a simple data step.

```
data notfound ;
  retain dsid;
  if _n_=1 then dsid=open("HAVE");
  if eof then dsid=close(dsid);      
  set required end=eof;
  if varnum(dsid,name) then delete;
  drop dsid;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try it with the `class` dataset in the `sashelp` library.

```
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
```

If you need this for one case, just program it like this:

```
data MISSING ;
    dsid=open('sashelp.class');
    length name $32;
    do name = 'sex', 'gender', 'AGE', 'Weight', 'shoe_size';
        if not varnum(dsid, name) then output;
    end;
    drop dsid;
proc print;
run;
```

If you regularly need this, you might use this macro:

```
%macro list_missing_fields(data, out, required);
    %macro _; %mend _; * restore syntax highlighting hack;
    data &out;
        dsid = open("&data");
        length name $32;
        %do no = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&required));
            name = "%scan(&required, &no)";
            if not varnum(dsid, name) then output;
        %end;
        drop dsid;
    run;
%mend;      
%list_missing_fields(sashelp.class, missing_in_class,
    sex gender AGE Weight shoe_size name sur_name);
```